# Best way to register a C++ service implementation library that can be loaded, registered and unloaded

Tags: c++, c++11, dynamic, service, shared-libraries

I want to provide service collection feature in my container application. As a part of this feature, I want to expose two interfaces, a '''Service''' and a '''ServiceRegistry'''. The idea is to make various service providers to add their service implementation to the service collection by using the registry interface. There is some overlap in the application users and the application providers community.

I am thinking of following options for the service interface:

```
  /// Option 1
  class Service
  {
      ...
  public:
      virtual void doWork() = 0;
      ...
  };

  /// Option 2
  using service_impl_type = std::function<void()>;
```

I am thinking of following options for the registry interface:

```
  /// Option A
  class ServiceRegistry
  {
      ...
  public:
      static void register( std::string const& name, 
                            shared_ptr<Service> const& service );
      ...
  };

  /// Option B
  namespace services
  {
      void register( std::string const& name, 
                     service_impl_type const& service );
  }
```

The application is part of a shared object '''libContainer.so''' and is loaded by an executable '''container'''. The new interfaces would be part of the '''libServices.so''' library. The  '''libContainer.so''' will depend on '''libServices.so'''.

The service providers are expected to deploy a library '''libSvcProviderXYZ.so''' containing their service implementation in a folder known to the application. The '''container''' executable loads the shared object dynamically (dlopen) and calls a known exported function '''registerYourself()''' that will be present in all the provider libraries. The '''registerYourself()''' is expected to call the service registry interface with an implementation of the service in a synchronous fashion.

My question is whether the provider shared object '''libSvcProviderXYZ.so''' can be unloaded some times after the '''registerYourself()''' completes successfully.

If I go with Option 1 and Option A (for service & registry), the xyz provider may provide the following in '''libSvcProviderXYZ.so''':

```
  class ServiceImpl : public Service
  {
  public:
      void doWork()
      {
          ...
      }
  };

  void registerYourself()
  {
      ServiceRegistry::register("xyz", std::make_shared<ServiceImpl>());
  }
```

In this case can I safely unload the provider shared object '''libSvcProviderXYZ.so''' after '''registerYourself()''' completes successfully? If it can be unloaded what happens to the '''ServiceImpl''' type information that is introduced by this provider library?

If I go with Option 2 and Option B (for service & registry), the xyz provider may provide the following in '''libSvcProviderXYZ.so''':

```
  class ServiceImpl
  {
  public:
      void operator()()
      {
      }
  };

  void registerYourself()
  {
      ServiceImpl impl;
      services::register("xyz", impl);
  }
```

In this case can I safely unload the provider shared object '''libSvcProviderXYZ.so''' after '''registerYourself()''' completes successfully? If it can be unloaded is it because of type-erasure of ServiceImpl once the instance is copied to std::function ?

Many thanks in advance for any help/advice in this regard!

Comment: `register` is a poor choice of name.  And no, code in unloaded dynamic library cannot run after the dynamic library is unloaded.  This is true regardless of how you wrap the code.  This kind of thing could possibly be "solved" (depending on your requirements), but you would need to actually post actual requirements.  "Best" is a matter of opinion.  "Is there a way to satisfy these requirements" is not.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Thanks for the feedback! Yes in actual implementation i would not use register as my interface function. Regarding requirements I thought my question was comprehensive. Is there anything you would like to know specifically? Thanks again!

Comment: You "ask about" unloading.  You don't say "I must be able to unload and still work".  You talk about how the dynamic library is loaded; you don't indicate what (if any) of it is requirements and what is just your idea.  You don't detail lifetime or ability to unregister requirements.  A shared ptr is valuable when you need shared lifetimes; so information about your lifetime **requirements** being missing makes it hard to reason about "do you need a shared ptr".

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Yes to be clear, the basic requirement is for the application container to be robust to the fact that provider libraries are dynamic and could potentially be unloaded after the provider implementation has been registered. I agree the shared_ptr is diverting attention from the gist of my question (above). Would it help if I replace it with a raw pointer to better illustrate my core question (concern)? Thanks

Comment: Ok, now what kind of behavior is permitted when a library is unloaded?  (A) It must work perfectly just as if the library wasn't unloaded.  (B) It must prevent the library from being unloaded.  (C) The service must be unregistered.  (note that overly restrictive requirements can lead to the answer of "this cannot be done")  - "what is best" is subjective, "can I solve these requirements, and if so how" is objective.  Please put objective requirements in your question (along side your attempt, and what goes wrong)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Thanks makes sense! The desired behavior after the unloading of provider implementation is for the injected provider implementation to work (may not be possible at all). However, I have been wondering about the type-erasure approach (Option 2 & Option B) in my question above. This has mainly been a thought experiment for me so far. I am definitely planning to evaluate my options. Before that I wanted to poll the community as well for some advice to see if I am on the right track or if it is a wild goose chase. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: So the only way to exec code in an unloaded implementation is to reload it, so you would need to record the path of the dll that loaded the code. Is that a path you want to go down?

Comment: @GemTaylor The requirement is that the container is robust to the fact that the provider libraries could potentially be unloaded. The ideal solution is to have the service available after they have been registered once (irrespective of what happens to the library that has the implementation). I understand that this may be impossible.

Comment: @AnandV I don't see how it can ever be "possible" to run something that has been completely deleted. By definition it has been deleted, so it cannot be run. Whatever you do to fix this requirement will fundamentally change the requirement, e.g. if you make a copy of the resource, then it has not been "completely deleted". If you decide to safely not run the component then iyou haven't run it.